# Culerity vs Selenium for Javascript Testing in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, culerity

In our eternal quest to integrate Javascript into our RSpec and Cucumber workflow we're evaluating [Culerity](http://github.com/langalex/culerity/tree/master) and are provisionally very excited about it.

Any advice on Culerity in general or specifically as compared to Selenium?

Comment: Use Capybara and you can have both =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On documentation alone, I'd go with Selenium:

[Selenium documentation.](http://seleniumhq.org/documentation/)

[Culerity documentation.](http://github.com/langalex/culerity/tree/master)

Does Culerity have a Firefox add-on to record test-scripts (does make things easy)
Which has the better track record?

I see Selenium as being better in these regards right now.

Answer (score 2):

I personally found Culerity to be a quite a bit buggier and more tempermental than Selenium.  I had several failing tests that turned out to be issues with Celerity rather than something wrong with the test or app.  A lot of time wasted :/